# How does Visual Studio determine the C# version for a project and where is it stored?

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I changed the language version from the Advanced option in the Build section in Project properties. I changed it from 5.0 to 6.0. The target framework of the project is .Net 4.6.2. The project file got checked out but I did not see any difference. Where is this information stored? How Visual Studio is able to identify the language version if nothing changes in the `.csproj` file?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it's in your `web.config` if you're using a web project. For Windows Forms, it's probably on `App.config`.

Comment: @Phiter: I'd expect it to be in the csproj file. App.config is more about execution time settings.

Comment: Please give more details about the kind of project you're building - it will make a big difference.

Comment: The configuration file specifies which CLR version you're targeting, it doesn't specify the language.  How could it?  The .exe or .dll is already compiled.

Comment: @DaisyShipton, I think you can set [compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.100).aspx) settings in the web.config. You can change the target framework version, perhaps not the C# target version. I'm not sure https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301726/Web-config-File-ASP-NET

Comment: @Phiter That's for views/pages, not c# code. The c# target is either in the csproj or the .csproj.user (cannot remember which)

Comment: @Phiter: Yes, that's fine for web - I was referring to your comment about Windows Forms using app.config. Apologies for not being clear. (For web there'd be two separate versions, potentially: one for the version you're using to build everything other than views, and one for the views that are built at execution time.)

Comment: Oh I see, that's for views. It'd be easier if OP had specified the target environment XD   Thanks for the information

Comment: @Phiter no, it wouldn't, because it doesn't matter. It is **always** in the same place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working under the false assumption that your csproj file hasn't change. Try pressing save, you should see a difference in there, a line like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <LangVersion>6</LangVersion> <!-- This line -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks [DavidG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg). I did not save it. As soon as I saved it, I found the difference. One more question what if the LangVersion tag is absent? Is it the latest major version for the framework?

Comment: The default is the latest major version which is currently 7.0.